# Size limit on option buying and selling

Tags: options, robinhood

While using Robinhood I have found that can buy/sell a maximum of 200 call options at a time. Is this a general rule for all trading clients at other brokers such as Ameritrade, Merrill Lynch, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an in house rule at Robinhood.

CBOE Position Limits are typically in the 25,000 to 250,000 contracts depending on the  capitalization of the underlying, the number of outstanding shares and the trading volume of the underlying  during the past 6 months.

That limit is the same for contracts exercised on the same side of the market during  any 5 consecutive market days.

There are some exceptions for qualified hedging strategies.

Google  "OCC Position Limits" if you want the exact numbers.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this only apply to writing calls, or buying them too? (It makes sense having a limit on writing them as you are effectively taking margin)

Comment: @Vality Buying Calls.

Comment: Position limits are calculated  in terms of the equivalent number of underlying shares.  For a long position, long calls are aggregated with short  puts written  on the same underlying.   For a short position, short calls are aggregated with long  puts.  OTC options positions are calculated separately from listed positions.  As an example, if the Position Limit  is 25,000 contracts, 15,000 long  XYZ calls and 10,000 short XYZ puts would be the limit.